# Как создать таблицу с различными типами ячеек в одном столбце?

Tags: c#, wpf

С Wpf знаком недавно, этап влюблённости быстро прошёл и началась бытовуха.
Нужно получить контрол, чтото вроде PropertyGrid, однако без использования аттрибутов.

На входе имею `Dictionary<string,Type> setupScetc`h (имя параметра-тип параметра) и метод валидации для этого setupScetch. Type может быть примитивным, `enum`-ом, или `MyStruct[]`. Для каждого из этих типов  нужен свой тип ячейки.

Дело дошло до кровавых мазолей на пальцах, ибо мы начали в рантайме генерировать типы под проперти грид, но это решение не даёт мне уснуть уже неделю своей великолепностью. Помогите побороть бессонницу...

Comment: хлороформ?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте для ячейки шаблон, в котором лежит [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms609797.aspx), для него определите [TemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector.aspx), который будет определять шаблоны для конкретного содержимого.

Answer (score 0):

Я неоднократно делал такие штуки.

`System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(тип или объект)` - главный метод для этого. Получаем описания свойств и динамически генерируем по ним контролы.

Если набор свойств объекта зависит от данных, реализуйте в нём `ICustomTypeDescriptor`. В этом интерфейсе можно перекрыть способ получения описания свойств.

Answer (score 0):

Помойму, человек хочет создать набор для разных типов ячеек. Похвально, я тоже в интернете искал норм. PropertyGrid. Если остановишься на нем, то вот неплохой и бесплатный контрол с открытым исходником, там есть уже своя система для добавления новых типов, вроде все не сложно, есть хорошие примеры
[WPF PROPERTY GRID](http://denisvuyka.wordpress.com/category/wpf/wpf-propertygrid/)